# Double loop with map() function in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, for-loop, google-earth-engine

In [Google Earth Engine Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server#looping), there is a recommendation to avoid `for()` loops. They recommend to use `map()` function as this example:

```
// to avoid
var clientList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  clientList.push(i + 1);
}
print(clientList);

// to use
var serverList = ee.List.sequence(0, 7);
serverList = serverList.map(function(n) {
  return ee.Number(n).add(1);
});
print(serverList);
```

I'm trying to select MODIS scenes from each month/year prior to compute VCI. So, the approach I'd take is with a double loop:

```
modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MYD13A1");

var modis_list = [];
for(var i = 1; i <13; i++) {
  for(var j = 2000; j <2018; j++){
    modis_list.push(modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(j, j, 'year')));
  }
}
print(modis_list);
```

Is there a way to replicate a double loop like this with `map()` function to reach a server-side approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you are just trying to understand GEE's `map()` function, and how would be the equivalent of a normal js `for loop`, the code would be:

```
var map_m = function(i) {
  i = ee.Number(i)
  var years = ee.List.sequence(2000, 2017)
  var filtered_col = years.map(function(j) {
    var filtered = modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
                        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(j, j, 'year'))
    return filtered
  })
  return filtered_col
}

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12)
var modis_list2 = months.map(map_m).flatten()
```

This code replicates a normal `for loop`. First, it goes item by item of the *years list*, and then item by item of the *months list*, and then, once you have year and month, filter the collection and add it to a list (`map` does that automatically). As you use 2 `map` functions (one over years and the other over months), you get a list of lists, so to get a list of `ImageCollection` use the `flatten()` function. Somehow the printed objects are a bit different, but I am sure the result is the same.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks you so much

Answer (score 9):

The easy way to do this is with a single map over the "months" you care about.

```
// Collect images for each month, starting from 2000-01-01.
var months = ee.List.sequence(0, 18*12).map(function(n) {
  var start = ee.Date('2000-01-01').advance(n, 'month')
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month')
  return ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MYD13A1").filterDate(start, end)
})
print(months.get(95))
```

This will return a list of ImageCollections.  Most months will have only 1 image, since MYD13A1 contains 16-day images, but some will have two.  Month 95 is Jan of 2008 and has two.

Alternatively, you could join the collection with a collection of dates, but this is simpler.

And you should prefer filterDate over calendarRange when possible, as it's optimized.

Comment: Great... I'll take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying I know nothing about Google Earth Engine and my info is from functional programming knowledge.

---

`map` is unique in that it doesn't generate the things it loops over. You start with a list and `map` iterates over each item in that list and transforms it.  If you don't have that list then map isn't a great fit.

It looks like you are creating a list with each month/year combo represented. I would break this into a few steps. Build the month and year lists, build the list that represents cartesian product of the 2 lists then transform to the `ee` objects.

```
var range = (from, to) => new Array(end-start+1).fill(0).map((_,i)=>i+from)
var cartesianProduct = (a, b) => // not gonna do this here but it returns pairs [ [ a[1], b[1] ], ... ]
var getEE = ([month, year]) => modis
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'));

var months = range(1,12);
var years = range(2000, 2017);
var data = cartesianProduct(months, years)
    .map(getEE)
```

There are likely better ways(like not iterating throught the whole list of `modis` each time we want a single month object (use a dictionary)) but the gist is the same.

Comment: Thanks, but code format of GEE is different. At this moment, `const` is not allowed.

Comment: Oh no problem, I edited the answer to use `var` instead.